How to aggregate confidence interval from spline into intervals correctly for Cox model?
Currently i'm estimating HR splines using mgcv::gam::coxph. My spline is nonlinear and has one turn, so i'd like to divide my spline into two sections given the turn and get conditional estimates for each interval (average HRs and its 95% CIs). Should I simulate the posterior in order to get aggregated CIs or I can just aggregate model-ready spline CIs on log scale?
library(mgcv)
library(gratia)
library(dplyr)

### Posterior
model <- gam(time ~ s(blood_pressure), data=df, family=cox.ph(), weights = status, method="REML")

smooth_samples(model, n=1000, select="s(blood_pressure)") %>% 
  mutate(flag=if_else(blood_pressure<=140, "lower_range", "upper_range")) %>%
  group_by(flag)%>%
  summarise(est = exp(mean(.value, na.rm = TRUE)),
            lower = exp(quantile(.value, 0.025, na.rm = TRUE)),
            upper = exp(quantile(.value, 0.975, na.rm = TRUE)))

### Simple aggregation
confint(model, parm=s(blood_pressure), n=1000, partial_match=T) %>%
  mutate(flag=if_else(blood_pressure<=140, "lower_range", "upper_range")) %>%
  group_by(flag)%>%
  summarise(est = exp(mean(.estimate)), 
            lower = exp(mean(.lower_ci)), 
            upper = exp(mean(.upper_ci)))

```


See RMS where the simple approach of getting differences in predicted values at chosen values of the covariate, then anti-logging them, is described.  You can do this in general with the R marginaleffects package.

Thank you Frank. But here you talk about getting differences in predicted values (i.e. Q2-Q1), I'd like to average estimates over a range of values (i.e. mean(est) for range between Q1 and Q2),- like what's the average estimate and its CI in range of 80-140, not the difference between 80 and 140 separately. Any idea on this?

"I'd like to divide my spline into two sections given the turn and get conditional estimates for each interval" runs the risks involved in binning continuous variables. If you want to illustrate the results of your model, a continuous display of hazard versus the continuous predictor would be most faithful to the data and most useful to your audience. Binning can lead the audience to a false impression of a sharp break in behavior at the cutoffs. An alternative is to choose specific representative values within each range.

Another potential problem with splitting into two sections is the type of average you would get for the intervals. The Cox coefficients are estimated in a log-hazard scale. The average log-hazard difference over an interval would typically be much different from the average hazard ratio, (HR) given the exponentiation of log-hazard to move to the hazard scale. An average hazard ratio is likely to be biased, dominated by regions of the curve with extreme HRs. That's another reason to use representative values within each interval instead.

The contrast.rms function in the rms package makes such averaging easy.
